# how to convert org.gson.JsonObject to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android

I construct the JsonObject on the server, convert it to a string, then send back to client. However, i am failing to reconstruct the json object in android client using `JSONObject x = new JSONObject(string)` without getting null pointer.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-191

Process: com.venon.jerseytwentythreetwentyfour, PID: 3034
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
  at com.venon.jerseytwentythreetwentyfour.Test$1.run(Test.java:45)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

Comment: Add the exception to your question so we know what you are dealing with.

Comment: see editted question with exception

Comment: Pls post the content of `string` (using `Log.d("string", string);` right above `JSONObject x = new JSONObject(string)`, and comment `JSONObject x = new JSONObject(string)` line for now), I guess it's null

Comment: I ran an individual test and found the conversion indeed worked, the problem was communication between my client and server

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use Gson in android as well. Nonetheless, you can parse a String as a JSONObject with `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);`

Comment: This doenst work when the jsonString is an org.gson.JsonObject

Comment: @VernonKawonza are u using GSON or JSON.?